# Equivalent definitions of ample bundles

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ag.algebraic-geometry

M. Atiyah in "VECTOR BUNDLES OVER AN ELLIPTIC CURVE" defined ample line bundle $E$ on $X$ as satisfying the following conditions:

1. Canonical map $H^0(X, E)\to E_x$ is surjective for any $x\in X$.
2. $H^q(X,E)=0$ for $q>0$.

But in standard textbooks like Hartshorne there is another definition:

$E^{\otimes n}$ is very ample for some $n\in \mathbb N$.

Are these definitions really equivalent? Where can I find proof of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a very ample line bundle does not need to be ample in the sense of the first definition (consider $\mathcal O(1)$ on a smooth plane curve of degree $>4$ or, more generally, on any smooth hypersurface of high enough degree). I do not know whether ampleness in the sense of the 1st definition implies ampleness in the sense of teh second definition.

Nowadays the standard definition of ampleness is as given in Hartshorne's book.

Comment: Wouldn't $E=\mathcal O_X$ satisfy the first condition on $X=\mathbb P^1$, without being ample?

Comment: Yes, I already realised that. Very ample line bundles usually don't have vanishing non-zero-th cohomologies. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @J.C.Ottem: $\mathcal O_X$ is not globally generated, so it does not meet the requirements of the 1st definition. 

Comment: @Serge: $\mathcal{O}_X$ is always globally generated!

Comment: @Laurent: What exactly do we mean by "globally generated"? OP gives a condition "$H^0(X,E)$ surjects onto `$\mathcal O_x$` for each $x\in X$"). If $X$ is proper and positive-dimensional (and, say, connected), this condition does not hold: a local ring of $X$ cannot be generated by constants only!

Comment: @Serge: If you take $E= \mathcal{O}_X$ and a point $x \in X$, from the exact sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-x) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_x \to 0$$ you see immediately that, since $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(-x))=0$, the map $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X) \to H^0(\mathcal{O}_x)$ is an isomorphism, so $(1)$ is satisfied.  

Comment: @Francesco: That's right of course if `$\mathcal O_x$` is quotient of `$\mathcal O_X$` by the ideal sheaf of the closed point $x$. However, by `$\mathcal O_x$` I meant the local ring of $X$ at $x$. More generally, by "sheaf generated by global sections" I meant a coherent sheaf $E$ on $X$ s.t. for each $x\in X$, germs at $x$ of sheaves of global sections of $E$ generate the stalk of $E$ at $x$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ample_line_bundle#Sheaves_generated_by_their_global_sections).

Comment: @Serge: the definition of Hartshorne, page 121 is clear: $E$ is generated by global sections if and only if it is a quotient of a free sheaf, i.e. a quotient of a direct sum of copies of $\mathcal{O}_X$. And $\mathcal{O}_X$ of course has this property!   

Comment: @Serge: the question is what is meant by "generate the stalk". With your phrasing, it should mean "generate the stalk $E_x$ as an `$\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$`-module". And then of course it is true for `$E=\mathcal{O}_{X}$`.  

In condition 1 of the question, "$E_x$" should be understood as the stalk at $x$ *tensored with the residue field*. An even then, that version of the definition works only if you work with rational points over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @Laurent @Francesco: sorry, you both are right.

Comment: Dear  @Francesco, @Laurent and @Serge,  the human condition would be less tragic if everybody notationally distinguished between  the sheaf stalk $\mathcal E_x$ of a locally free sheaf $\mathcal E$ and the fibre  $E(x)=\mathcal E(x)=\mathcal E_x \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}} \mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_x$ of the associated vector bundle $E$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be an elliptic curve.

Then a divisor $E$ which is ample in the sense of the first definition is necessarily ample in the usual sense. Conversely, if it is ample in the usual sense and $\deg E \geq 2$ then it is ample in the sense of the first definition.

In fact, assume that $E$ ample in the sense of the first definition. Then $(2)$ implies that $\mathcal{O}_X(E) \neq \mathcal{O}_X$ and  $(1)$ implies that $\dim H^0(X, E) \geq 2$, because a non-trivial divisor with $\dim H^0(X, E) =1 $ on an elliptic curve cannot be globally generated. Then by $(2)$ and Riemann-Roch it follows $$\deg E = \dim H^0(X, E) \geq 2,$$ hence $E$ is ample in the usual sense by [Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, Corollary 3.3 page 308].

Conversely, assume that $E$ is ample in the usual sense and $\deg E \geq 2$. This last condition implies that $|E|$ is base-point free on $X$, hence $E$ is globally generated and $(1)$ holds. Moreover, since $\omega_X = \mathcal{O}_X$, by Kodaira Vanishing Theorem and Serre duality one deduces $(2)$. So $E$ is ample in the sense of the first definition.